# CSS: rtl input element with ltr insert

Tags: html, css

I used rtl direction (for persian language) in html tag for whole document. But I have some input element for username or email address (as you know, these are english and must be ltr). I google and find some script for auto-direction. They worked, but if I have **rtl placeholder** for input, the placeholder text also will be ltr!
Can you guide me?
I want something like this:
 [sample]: http://sumdroid.pe.hu/sample.jpg "please see this image"

whole document is rtl, placeholder is rtl, but input element insert is ltr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the browser specific pseudo calls to the placeholder should sort your issue out

```
input[type="text"]:-moz-placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}
input[type="text"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}
input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    text-align: right;
}

.input{
direction: rtl;
}

.input:focus{
  text-align: left;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Comment: thanks. But just css pseudo code is efficient and solve problem. The rest of styles in not needed and with these code, result will be different and not the thing that I want (as shown in attached image)

Answer (score 5):

You can use this way:

html

```
<input class="input" type="text" value="رمزعبور" name="" id=""  onfocus="if (this.value == 'رمزعبور') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'رمزعبور';}"/>
```

css

```
.input{
  direction: rtl;
}
.input:focus{
  text-align: left;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/mehrabi/pen/yePmEZ

Comment: thanks. This is a tricky solution. But I mean using placeholder, not using value as placeholder.